# Star schema design feedback

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema, star-schema-datawarehouse

I work for an OTC company.

Here is the background on the workflow.
Taker (Buyer) --> Requests a quote on derivatives --> Maker(Quoter) responds with quotes (bid/ask) ---> Taker either buys/sells ( traded) or takes no action on the quote. The quote can be sent and received from multiple makers.

Let me know if my star schema is correct.

I am thinking of takers, makers as dimension tables. Requests as one fact table and quotes as another fact table. Is this approach correct?

Comment: A dimensional model design is based on your reporting requirements, not on the structure/workflow of a source system - so without knowing what your reporting requirements  are it’s impossible to comment on your design. In any case, just asking if a star schema is correct is too broad a question for this forum: you need to ask a specific, focussed question

Comment: @NickW Typical reporting questions would be 1) total dollar amount by different derivates by day/month by exchange 2) total number of quotes quoted by makers in last x days and break down by traded/ cancelled/ expired (no action)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you’ve started to identify your measures, once you’ve identified them all the next steps are:

1. Define the grain if each measure; measures with the same grain can exist in the sane fact table; measures with different grains need to be in different fact tables
2. For each fact table, identify the entities you need to filter or aggregate the facts; this gives you your dimensions